# How to mount windows "downloads" folder on a vhdx file

Tags: windows, vhd, home-directory

I'd like to know how I can mount a vhdx image as `%userprofile%\Downloads` folder  in windows 10.

When I use the 'disk management' tool it doesn't let me click 'ok' when I've selected the 'downloads' folder.

EDIT:
1st issue solved: I wasn't deleting the `desktop.ini`

Now I need to set it as automount (I don't like to have, each time I turn my PC on, to reconfigure that folder)

Comment: The mount point needs to be an empty folder. Try mounting your VHDX on an empty folder, to see if this works.  You could then rename Downloads to something else, create a new folder called Downloads, mount the VHDX there and if required copy in the current contents of Downloads to the VHDX mounted Folder.

Comment: Didn't seen that 'desktop.ini' (hidden system file), I checked only for hidden files. Now the folder mounts (manually) but not on system start-up

Comment: This should help: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-automatically-mount-d623ce34.

Comment: Thanks, anyway I solved the problem by 'moving' the folder using windows option. It'S be an image but solves my need (move downloaded data from ssd to HDD)